# Head/tail breaks classification algorithm in R

Tags: r, cartography

I am trying to implement the head/tail breaks classification algorithm in R ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head/tail_Breaks)). This relatively new algorithm is a less computationally expensive alternative to other classification methods used in Cartography for highly skewed data.

So far, I have been looking as template a code in Python ([see here](https://github.com/chad-m/head_tail_breaks_algorithm/blob/master/htb.py)) with relatively success. Here is my implementation in R:

```
# fake data to classify
pareto_data <- c()
for (i in 1:100){
  pareto_data[i] <- (1.0/i)^1.16
}

# head/tail breaks algorithm
ht <- function(data){
  ln <- length(data)
  mn <- mean(data)
  res <- append(c(),mn) # this is where I was hopping to store my output
  head <- subset(data,data>=mn)
  while (length(head)>=1 & length(head)/ln <= 0.40){
    print(res)
    return(ht(head))
  }
  #return(res)
}

ht(pareto_data)
```

As a result of running above code, I have been able to print the following:

```
[1] 0.03849691
[1] 0.1779904
[1] 0.4818454
```

This output is very likely the same of running the original Python code I have been using as template. However, I have not been successful in storing it in either a vector or a list.

I would be really thankful if you can give hints to overcome this problem and also to improve my code (which is not exactly the same as the original one in Python, particularly in the conditions of the `while` statement).

Comment: Ok it doesn't work because in that python function, it stores in into a global variable.. and in R, your functions cannot alter your global variable... You don't really need to rewrite the python code exactly.. it's a bit let's say unconventional

Comment: Or you really want to write a recursive function ?

Comment: yes, I do. This algorithm is recursive

Comment: Ok see below solution by Rui.. I think that should work :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible recursive version of the algorithm could be the following.

```
ht_breaks <- function(x){
  ht_inner <- function(x, mu){
    n <- length(x)
    mu <- c(mu, mean(x))
    h <- x[x > mean(x)]
    if(length(h) > 1 && length(h)/n <= 0.4){
      ht_inner(h, mu)
    } else mu
  }
  ht_inner(x, NULL)
}

pareto_data <- (1.0/(1:100))^1.16
ht_breaks(pareto_data)
#[1] 0.03849691 0.17799039 0.48184535
```

Comment: FWIW this version uses `>=` and `<=` where the Python version has `>` and `<`, so the results may differ in some rare cases.

Comment: @KentJohnson You are right, thanks. I changed the `>=`. But kept the other one, it's what the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head/tail_Breaks#Method) uses. (It's a link to the pseudo-code.)

Comment: @RuiBarradas would you be fine if I integrate this in `classInt`? Thanks

Comment: @dieghernan Yes, feel free to. Glad to help!

Comment: @RuiBarradas see https://github.com/r-spatial/classInt/pull/21

Comment: @dieghernan Nice :).

Comment: Already implemented on `classInt`, see vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/classInt/vignettes/headtailsR.html

Comment: @dieghernan A new algorithm, implemented and included in a package by useR's. Isn't open source the best?